# Produced artifact has too many layers of folders

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have the following pipeline that builds a ASP.NET Core 5 Web project, but the artifact produced has the following structure

```
ProjectName.zip
   Content
     D_C
       a
         1
           s
             ProjectName
              obj
                release
                  package
                    PackageTmp
                      (Finally The actual content) as it should be
   archive.xml
   parameters.xml
   systeminfo.xml
```

I simply want my zip to be the content of `packagetmp` without any parent folders

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: ''myfeed'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: "Upload Artifacts"
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `msbuildArgs` as below to generate the artifacts as files instead of a zip file. And then you can use [Archive files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops) to zip the artifacts. See below:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)" /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

The msbuildArgs in above example will output the artifacts to folder `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` unzipped.

Then after VSBuild Task. You can add Archive files task to zip the artifacts:

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive task'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Temp/ProjectName.zip'
```

Above example will zip the artifacts in `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, and save the zip file in `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Temp/ProjectName.zip`

Then in the `PublishBuildArtifacts` task. Set the `PathtoPublish` to folder `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Temp`

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: "Upload Artifacts"
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Temp'
```

You should get a zip file with the content of packagetmp only.